# cpanel - full restoration from the server and a cpmove restoration?

Tags: linux, centos

What's the difference between full restoration from the server and a cpmove restoration?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/WHMDocs/RestoreFullbackup) is not completely clear, but in my experience, this is the difference:

A full restoration from the server refers to an earlier (automatic) backup that is taken and stored in an appropriate directory (such as `/cpbackup/backup/...`). You input a username, and it will extract the latest backup and restore it.

A cpmove file is one generated when you run `/scripts/pkgacct username` at a SSH terminal, it will generate a `cpmove-username.tar.gz` file which you can then copy to any server, and restore the account completely. Users can also generate their own cpmove files by using the generate full backup feature inside their cPanel account, although these files are named `backup_datetime_username.tar.gz` rather than `cpmove-username.tar.gz`, even though they are of the same format.

Comment: Really Thanks, does cpmove contain database?

Comment: Yes, if you extract the file, you will see a `homedir` in which you can explore their `public_html` files, but also a `mysql` folder with one file for a `mysqdump` of each database, plus a file that holds the credentials (which MySQL users can access which databases).

Comment: Thanks again, I remember once I created a full backup and there was no database, I searched and seems it's an issue with cPanel. but I'll try cpmove script

Comment: No problem - the database *should* be there by design, I'm sure of that much. If it isn't there, it's possible that the MySQL server was dead while the backup was in progress, or the backup is corrupt.